# Set Height Css Class After Page Load in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, ecmascript-6

I need to set the `mainContainer` class `height` to the iframe height on page load.
Right now its setting the height BUT its cut. Maybe this code is wrong? `const iframeHeight = document.getElementById('productIFrame')[0].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';`

```
<div class="mainContainer">
    <iframe id="productIFrame" src="https://sample.com" title="" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: none"></iframe>
</div>

<style>
    .mainContainer {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const iframeHeight = document.getElementById('productIFrame').contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
  document.getElementsByClassName("mainContainer")[0].style.height = iframeHeight;
</script>
```

Comment: Will this work as a StackSnippet?

Comment: What happens when you put the script in the window load event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically set the height of the iframe based on the loaded iframe content?  If yes, there are many [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+iframe+dynamic+height) that can help.

Comment: @Yogi. No. I'm trying to set the `mainContainer`'s height based on the iframe height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**QUESTION SOLVED!**

Solution would be to add postMessage function in the iframe level.
and on the main page, you need to add an event listener and extract the height coming from that and assign it to the `mainContainer` class.

Comment: Note that this solution only applies to iframes with cross domain content and assumes one has permissions to add messaging scripts to the other page.  There are simpler solutions when the page is in the same domain.  See duplicate questions: [How to get height of iframe cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223239/how-to-get-height-of-iframe-cross-domain) and [Adjust width and height of iframe to fit with content in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819416/adjust-width-and-height-of-iframe-to-fit-with-content-in-it)

Comment: @Yogi. Can you help me with my latest question?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run on local

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
        const iFrame = document.getElementById('productIFrame');
        iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.style.margin = "0 0 0 0";
        const iframeHeight = iFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
        document.getElementsByClassName("mainContainer")[0].style.height = iframeHeight;
    });
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.mainContainer {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
 <iframe frameborder="0" border="0" cellspacing="0"
        style="border-style: none; margin: 0;" id="productIFrame"  title="" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: none"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: `SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object`

Comment: yes, but it work

Comment: Above error is specific to Chrome check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29984435/4007628

Comment: My code works now but I just have to add `[0]`. `document.getElementsByClassName("mainContainer")[0].style.height = iframeHeight;`. Problem is is that its not getting the whole iframe height? Its cut out

Comment: Try use scrollHeight

Comment: Same issue it cuts out

Comment: Do you add margin: 0 !important for html and body?

Comment: Same thing :(((

Comment: I did update. What is your browser?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the document.readyState method, and fire your logic once page has loaded.

Something like the below may fix it for you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        const iframeHeight = document.getElementById('productIFrame').contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
        document.getElementsByClassName("mainContainer").style.height = iframeHeight;
    }
}
```

Comment: Documentation can be found @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState